# Failed to load resource:unsupported URL wkwebview-bridge://invoke

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, wbwebviewconsole

`WBWebViewConsole` is not giving any logs. Earlier it worked but for some reason its not working now in swift.I think it's not compatible with swift.

For any log that's created in js giving this error

> Failed to load resource:unsupported URL wkwebview-bridge://invoke

Comment: You might be overriding `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` of  WBWKWebView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be overriding `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` in the instance of `WBWKWebView`

If you want to do any implementation do it in the `WBWKWebView`'s `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` and handle respectively.